# Subgroups of Z4×Z2×Z2 isomorphic to Z4×Z2??

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

Describe the six distinct subgroups of Z4×Z2×Z2 which are isomorphic to Z4×Z2. 
 Prove that the six subgroups on your list are distinct. 
 Prove that there are no more than six.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start: The only elements of $Z_4\times Z_2\times Z_2$ of order $4$ are $(\pm 1, 0,0), (\pm 1, 1, 0), (\pm 1, 0, 1), (\pm 1, 1, 1)$. One of these must be sent to $(1,0)$.

Comment: Your hint hides the OP's question's answer...:) +1

Comment: What do you mean？